# <suffix> invalid DN 21 (Invalid syntax) on Converting slapd.conf OpenLdap

Tags: replication, openldap

Actually i want to configure ldap as master-slave replication using syncrepl method,
On any reference which i found,I'm running on Centos 6 machine and openldap v2.4.23.
I following step by step on http://admin.shamot.cz/?p=230#sthash.cKuGZQAu.dpbs
Which using configuration from slapd.conf.

But recently on openldap version 2.4 and above, **slapd.conf** have been change into cn=config.

based on http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html said that i can converting slapd.conf to cn=config format.

So i try to convert my slapd.conf to cn=config.

So for this purpose i try to make slapd.conf file on server which have role provider like bellow:

```
database bdb
suffix dc=mydomain,dc=org
rootdn cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=org
directory /var/lib/ldap/db
index objectclass,entryCSN,entryUUID eq

overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100

database config
rootpw mypassword
```

Then i try to convert that file using slaptest command, but i got error message like bellow :

```
$ slaptest -f slapd.conf -v
slapd.conf: line 2: <suffix> invalid DN 21 (Invalid syntax)
slaptest: bad configuration file
```

Actually my suffix is absolutely right, but why always "invalid DN"
How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with too minimal of a file, I added a few extra details and it works

```
#slapd.conf

#schemas to use
include /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

#log
pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

########################################
#####   dbm database definitions    ####
########################################

database bdb
suffix dc=server,dc=com
rootdn cn=Manager,dc=server,dc=com
rootpw secret

#database directory
directory       /var/lib/ldap

#end
```

According to [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=uk&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c01978918) you might only be missing the pidfile location as it changed between versions but you will eventually add the rest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may need quotes around the DNs.  Try `suffix "dc=mydomain,dc=org"`, and quote the DN in the following line also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
```

at the top of the file.

Possibly also the database module for the db backend you want

```
moduleload back_bdb
```